# not able to declare an append command on an array in iOS

Tags: ios, arrays, append, double

when trying to append a value to first initialize the array in the code body

```
var aValue = [Double]()
var bValue = [Double]()

aValue.append(0.0)
bValue.append(0.0)
```

the program tells me that they are not allowed above the class declaration

if trying to move it under the class declaration, it won't work either, and when trying to put it under its own button, only one of the "appends" works, but the other doesn't

Comment: have you imported UIkit?

Answer (score 0):

I just tested this in a new iOS project and it works fine. I'm guessing you either aren't using the standard tools (and aren't getting the Swift Standard Library somehow?), or for some reason it wants you to import Foundation, which shouldn't be necessary.

The only other thing I can think of is someone has overridden `append` in your project, possibly on an extension that explicitly extends `Array<Double>` and you're somehow in conflict with that.